# JMeter - 350 Concurrent Users load testing fails due to "Timeout performing EVAL" and 500 INTERNAL SERVAR ISSUE

Tags: jmeter

I'm performing load test in my application which is registration application for schools.
So I'm performing load test for the registration scenario and when I perform load test with JMeter for 350 concurrent users using Thread group with 1 ramp up secs , I'm facing the below issue's ,

1. Timeout performing EVAL
2. 500 - The request timed out.
3. 502 - Internal server error.

Can any one suggest on this whether it is issue from JMeter tool or the issues is from the application side.

Answer (score 0):

Normally HTTP Status Codes [500](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500) and above indicate server-side error so most probably your application under test is not capable of handling 350 concurrent users, so basically you've found the [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing).

Next actions would be identifying

1. So called [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html) - the maximum number of users which your application can support before performance starts degrading (response time increases and throughput decreases)
2. [Breaking point](https://mcminncoeda.org/testing-systems-to-the-breaking-point/) - you can state that 350 users are not supported, however I don't think you have information how many are really supported before the application starts throwing errors
3. The cause of the bottleneck which might be in:

   - incorrect configuration of the application and middleware - can be checked by manual inspection of configuration files and logs
   - lack of resources (i.e. CPU, RAM, Swap, Disk, Network, etc.) - can be checked using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)
   - error in the application (inefficient algorithm, large objects, not closed handles, etc.) - can be checked using [profiler tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools)